# Sum of Absolute Difference (SAD) with window size and search length for 1D

Tags: matlab, optimization, sum

If I have two data(1D), `in1` and `in2`, which are related to each other, however, there're some small shift of the second data as compared to the first one. So to locally match these two data, I used SAD. However, I can't get the right result. I have few uncertainties:

(1) Since the window is sliding across the second data set with the search length of `sl`, but with window size of `bs`, it will exceed the matrix dimension. How can I solve this? I use `padarray`, but this will not return accurate result at the end of the matrix.

(2) This looping method seem to be inefficient, any way to optimize it?

Mathematically, the whole process can be represented by(2D, but I'm porting it to 1D, that's x-axis only):
[image]

where `I_c=in1`, `I_r=in2`

Visually:

[image]

This is the code I implemented, please have a look.

```
function [ shift ] = sad1( in1, in2, bs, sl )

[m, n]=size(in1); %assume 1D, m=1
diplacement=zeros(1,n);
in2=padarray(in2,[0 sl-1]);
for i=1:n-bs
    %within search length
    block1=in1(:,i:i+bs);
    for j=i:i+sl
            %Compute SAD
            SAD = sum(abs(block1 - in2(:,j:j+bs)));
            %Save
            if exist('min_SAD','var') ~=1
                min_dis=j;
                min_SAD=SAD;
            elseif SAD<min_SAD
                min_dis=j;
                min_SAD=SAD;
            end
    end
    clear min_SAD;
    diplacement(1,i)=min_dis;

end
shift=diplacement;
end
```

Portion of actual data:

```
in1=[5372.46352651418   5257.08068764610    8042.76812761160    5833.32402142968    9491.43952200090    11856.2444355907    3326.33430840502    4217.67349421085    2894.89977584527    3708.35458683153    5924.60060483391    5802.91781076346    3591.61375542073    4235.09092237336    5127.74439876322    4647.02050902984    5191.28422148863    5379.99663160256    5355.36370540952    4966.78807113959];

in2=[8433.00343662079   7471.02426850808    9859.06780580582    12423.7461297648    3833.32998993304    4931.62052706979    2620.01013123014    4819.49730306015    5755.79698619561    6036.21578538532    3608.11913105578    3944.14593740411    5554.92517145851    4741.08692339139    5353.01966043511    5475.83430522947    4854.65355872352    4747.04946476863    4994.36729161458    5714.79600924313];
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried at looking at the correlation between the two signals?  Since you're going into 1D and you want to determine the amount of shift between the two signals, it would make sense to look at this in a correlation perspective no?

Comment: Hi, you mean using function `xcorr`? `in1` and `in2` is the summation of gradient intensity of image1 and image2 respectively in x-axis, Since I'm determine the shifting in pixels by using this method, I'm not sure is that the correct way to do it. Do you think `xcorr` could give me the shift? And by least-square fit the shifts, I expect the constant term is the global shift of the two images, any opinion on this matter? Thanks!